# how to convert MKMapPoint to CGPoint

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, mkmapview

Can any one explain how to convert MKMapPoint to CGPoint ? I need to draw path using latitude and longitude on a UIView.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Updated answer.......

```
CGPoint newCenter = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:coordinates toPointToView:self.mapView];
```

Comment: Gave the OP a -1 because the accepted answer doesn't take in the type that they wanted to convert from.  Unhelpful for those of us searching for an answer to the original question.

Comment: Please do not copy someone else's answer.

Comment: @Matt Yes but i posted answer  earlier other than. Its not copy i modified it only.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh you therefore need to add you change marked as an update. Otherwise it seems as if the other answers copied yours.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer coverts CLLocationCoordinate2D to CGPoint, which is not what is asked in the actual question. For those looking for the full answer here it is:

```
MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointMake(22.1, 34.4);//example

//first convert MKMapPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D
CLLocationCoordinate2D mapPointCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(mapPoint);

//second convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to CGPoint
CGPoint pointAsCGPoint = [self.mapView convertCoordinate: mapPointCoordinate toPointToView: self.mapView];
```

Comment: Before anyone downvotes:  the accepted answer was edited after my post, so now it seems like my post is a copy. Trust the upvotes :)